# C# and breakpoints - do we have any magician in here?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have this:

```
public static void ByLinkText(string text)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Setup.Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(text)).Click();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

(The weird code in the middle is selenium - lets just skip that, it's not the case here)

Okay, so I have this `ByLinkText()` method, what you don't see here, is that I repeat this method infinitely until this middle thingy will execute correctly and then hit that `return` after.

So: This middle code is NOT executing correctly, and I want to know why, so what am I doing? I put a breakpoint in the catch section. What is happening? Nothing (and `ByLinkText()` still keeps going infinitely!).

Now, you would tell me "Hey! That middle code is just not throwing anything!", but oh sweet wishes... That middle code can do two things: either throw something at me, or do it like it should ([prove1](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) and [prove2](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click%28%29)).

So finally, what is this all about? About breakpoints. As soon as I put my breakpoint on that `return` (right after magical code!) that code executes properly! HOW in the programical world is that possible, that breakpoint repairs my application!?

Comment: Breakpoints affect the system under test. Could be a race condition, for example.

Comment: Have you tried setting VS to break on exceptions?

Comment: Is your actual catch also empty? If so, depending on the optimization settings you have on the compiler it could be optimized away. Nothing there, no breakpoint.

Comment: TRWTF is raising exceptions and using exception handlers to handle non-exceptional conditions.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde: Nothing else running in parrallel.

Comment: @WillA: How can I do that?

Comment: @RomanGruber: Yes it's empty, but always when there is an error, my debugget catches that.

Comment: @ojek: Debug menu, Exceptions... - check one or more of the "Thrown" checkboxes - you'll probably only need to check the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox - click OK.

Comment: @WillA: Okay, i did it and guess what, code works perfectly. :D

Comment: @ojek: Don't ask for x because you want to do y... and *certainly don't tell us to ignore y*! You don't need to throw&catch exceptions infinitely to wait for an element. What happens when your boss calls you and threatens to fire you because a client has complained about the application "not working"? If it weren't for the sloppy use of exceptions in logic, at least you'd have a nice exception message and stack trace to help you debug and fix the problem.

Comment: STOP tagging this question with `magic`, it doesn't relate at all! **Describes things known as "magic strings" or "magic numbers". These are hard coded variables that cannot be changed at runtime.**

Answer (score 2):

When breakpoints make your application behave it means that there is probably a timing issue with your code. Whenever you stop at a break point the stop introduces a delay that may let other processing go on without error.

This is why you sometimes see `Thread.Sleep(N);` thrown into code here and there. That's a coder throwing his/her arms up and saying "I don't know. Just put a Sleep in there."

In fact, give it a try. Put a Thread.Sleep(3000); where the break point goes and see what happens. I don't ever recommend that this be the solution but it could be a good test of the theory.

Comment: Did it, 10 second break did nothing. :D

Answer (score 2):

I think this has more to do with selenium than you seem to believe.  Have a look at implicit and explicit waits for finding the element.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Another thing to try is to save the IWebElement result into a temp var, put on small sleep and then click it.  Sometimes the browser ui can't handle the commands as fast as selenium issues them.

```
var el = Setup.Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(text));
Thread.Sleep(750);
el.Click();
```

Comment: Did exactly what you said - no results at all! This things start to work only when I put a breakpoint on it...

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding a call to System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() instead.  Or writen the exception.ToString() result to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel here. Selenium can do this method for you:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm