# Selenium only working with breakpoint in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium to manipulate TestRail test cases. I am using this because the TestRail API is sparse and doesn't allow you to upload your log results.

I have everything set up and it runs with out problems until I reach the very end. When selenium hits enter on the Add Test Result (submit button) it tells me an error has occurred. The very odd thing is that if I step through it will submit with no errors.

To try and fix this I added a sleep for x seconds. I have tried sleeping for 2-20 seconds.

Here is a snippet of code that I am running.

```
        try
        {
            OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(testName));
            element.Click();


            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("addResult")).Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Add Attachment")).Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("attachment")).SendKeys(testCase.LogLocation);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=" + "\"" + "attachmentForm" + "\"" + "]/div[2]/button/span[1]")).Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=" + "\"" + "addResultVersion" + "\"" + "]")).SendKeys(testCase.Version);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=" + "\"" + "addResultStatus" + "\"" + "]")).SendKeys(testCase.Status.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=" + "\"" + "addResultComment" + "\"" + "]")).SendKeys(testCase.Comment);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=" + "\"" + "addResultElapsed" + "\"" + "]")).SendKeys(testCase.ElapsedTime.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=" + "\"" + "addResultAssignTo" + "\"" + "]"));
            SelectElement clickThis = new SelectElement(element);
            clickThis.SelectByText("Shawn Rioux");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=" + "\"" + "addResultDefects" + "\"" + "]")).SendKeys(testCase.Defects);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=" + "\"" + "addResultSubmit" + "\"" + "]"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            //If i set a break point on this line and remove the sleep it works some how :(
            Console.WriteLine("Page submitted");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed at an element " + e.Message);
        }
```

The weirdest part is if I set a break point on the line after `element.SendKeys` and remove the sleep everything works like a charm and adds the result perfect. At this point I am fairly certain it isn't a race condition since if I remove the sleep and set a break point AFTER the send keys it works, but I could be wrong. Any insight would be helpful

I have also looked at [C# and breakpoints - do we have any magician in here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455845/c-sharp-and-breakpoints-do-we-have-any-magician-in-here) and the `WebDriverWait` method in there didn't work for me unless I set a breakpoint.

Comment: You know that XPath allows single quotes: `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='addResultSubmit']"))`. Nasty! Anyway, if a breakpoint makes it all work, that definitely sounds like a timing problem. Could you show more code? The page you are coding against?

Comment: Sure i have added more code. But it being a timing issue why if i set the break point AFTER the enter key it works? :( As for the webpage i don't know how to post that since it require login/pw to get into

Comment: I found out a solution, I have it sleep for 1 second after the enter key is pressed and that fixed it thanks!